# Is there any way I can undo a drawn pixel in win32gui?

Tags: python, win32gui

I'm trying to undo pixels set in win32gui using win32gui.SetPixel()

I tried getting all the previous pixels in the given area I was drawing in and replacing them with their previous colors after finishing my drawing but that was too slow, my question is that is there a direct function that replaces all the pixels you set to the previous or undos?

```
import win32gui
import win32api

dc = win32gui.GetDC(0)
win32gui.SetPixel(dc, 0, 0, win32api.RGB(255, 0, 0))
win32gui.Undo() # theoretical function
```